# CSS :first-child pseudo-element

Tags: css, html

Why is my code not working as intended? background-color of the first article must be green. How I can do it without classes or id? P.S. I'm sorry but my post needs more text. I'm sorry but my post needs more text.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>stack</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_new.css">
    </head>

    <body> 
        <section>
            <h1>This is H1 header</h1>

            <article>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit 

                </p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 

                </p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 

                </p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body> 
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
     section article:first-child {
    background-color: green;
}

    section article:last-child {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: because the first article isn't the first child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually first child of section tag is **h1** not article. So use below code instead,

```
section article:first-of-type {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

article is not the first-child of section - its h1

the first/last child selector does only target if article is the first or last child of its container.

possible css:

```
section article{
  background-color:green;
}
section article + article{
  background-color:transparent;
}
section article:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/rn4wgho2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 ![enter image description here][1]
```

h1 required to remove the plug out of the section

## This is H1 header

```
        <article>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit 

            </p>
        </article>

        <article>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 

            </p>
        </article>

        <article>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 

            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
```